# How often do shops restock?

Tags: diablo-iii

If an NPC merchant has no items that are to my liking, how long do I have to wait before the shop restocks it's inventory?

Comment: I smell a bounty coming for this one...?

Comment: @Foxtrot guess we'll find out in a couple days :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to wait at all if you aren't currently engaged in a  co-op game. Just log out and log in. When the world is re-created, all of the vendors will restock!

(N.B., this will regenerate all random areas, destroying any loot you might've left on the ground on the other side of your town portal (along with the portal itself), so make sure you've cleaned up and are ready to hop a waypoint and reeler to wherever you left off.)

Comment: So this is the only way to renew the shops' stocks ?

Comment: It's the only way to force it to happen on demand, any time you want.

Comment: This is a good answer for merchants in town, but not useful when the merchant in question only spawns occasionally, such as Vendel the Armorsmith.

Answer (score 3):

Exiting the game you are in and creating a new one will refresh the shop's inventory. This is a quicker way of looking for a specific item from shops.

I'll try to test how long in-game time it takes for shops to refresh when I can log back in.

Hope this helps a little in the mean time :).

Answer (score -1):

I generally port back to town every 45 min (need to take a lot of breaks!) and I always check the vendors when I return to town.  I would say every other time the vendors have had new items (so aprox an hour and a half, maybe less though deff not more than that).  Mind you I'm only in normal, so no idea if its different on higher levels.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you have a source or proof the items changed?  I have played in long sessions and I don't notice the stock changing.

Comment: No I don't have a source or proof, just something I noticed while playing.  Personally, on my normal playthrough on act1 & act2, I would say the items have been different every 2 times I jump back to town, which is aprox an hour and 30 min /shrug.  No idea if its different for other people, but I almost always have new gear up on the merchants.